# Why is this code using multiple types of quotes

Tags: clojure, macros, quote

From : The Joy of Clojure

```
(defn contextual-eval [ctx expr]
  (eval
   `(let [~@(mapcat (fn [[k v]] [k `'~v]) ctx)]
      ~expr)))
```

Now if I call

```
(contextual-eval '{a 1 b 2} '(+ a b))
```

It returns **3** as expected.

But why the use of **`'~v** instead of just **v** ?

If I remove eval.. so that the function looks like this

```
(defn contextual-eval [ctx expr]
  `(let [~@(mapcat (fn [[k v]] [k v]) ctx)]
    ~expr))
```

and then call

```
(eval (contextual-eval '{a 1 b 2} '(+ a b)))
```

It still returns **3** as expected.

So I'm not sure why **`'~v** is used when eval is inside
the function body.

Comment: Which edition & page number?

Comment: **Second edition, Page 176 - Chapter 8 Macros**
 
Sorry in the second example, I had forgotten to remove eval.  So fixed it

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is a typo, I think.  This code shows what is happening, and what should happen:

```
(defn contextual-eval [ctx expr]
  (spy :01 ctx)

  (spy :02 (mapcat (fn [[k v]] [k `'~v]) ctx))
  (spy :03 `(let [~@(mapcat (fn [[k v]] [k `'~v]) ctx)] ~expr) )

  (spy :02a (mapcat (fn [[k v]] [k v]) ctx))
  (spy :03a `(let [~@(mapcat (fn [[k v]] [k v]) ctx)] ~expr) )

  (eval `(let [~@(mapcat (fn [[k v]] [k v]) ctx)] ~expr) )
  )

(dotest
  (nl)
  (spy :10
    (contextual-eval '{a 1 b 2}
      '(+ a b)))
  (nl)
  (spy :20
    (contextual-eval '{a 1
                       b (+ a 3)}
      '(+ a b)))
  )
```

We get results for first run:

```
:01 => {a 1, b 2}

:02 => (a (quote 1) b (quote 2))
:03 => (clojure.core/let [a (quote 1) b (quote 2)] (+ a b))

:02a => (a 1 b 2)
:03a => (clojure.core/let [a 1 b 2] (+ a b))

:10 => 3
```

Second run:

```
:01 => {a 1, b (+ a 3)}

:02 => (a (quote 1) b (quote (+ a 3)))
:03 => (clojure.core/let [a (quote 1) b (quote (+ a 3))] (+ a b))

:02a => (a 1 b (+ a 3))
:03a => (clojure.core/let [a 1 b (+ a 3)] (+ a b))

:20 => 5
```

by converting "`'~v" into just "v" it does what it should.

---

P.S.  While JoC has a lot of good stuff, it is very advanced and should be more like your fifth Clojure book, not the first (it was my first Clojure book, and I got very confused).  You would be well-served by starting out with:

- Getting Clojure
- Living Clojure
- Clojure for the Brave & True

---

### Update:

I would do it a little differently.  There is really no need for the `mapcat`.  Notice the `(:use ...)` clause in the `(ns ...)` form:

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use demo.core tupelo.core tupelo.test)) 

(defn contextual-eval [ctx expr]
  (spy :01 ctx)
  (spy :02 (seq ctx))
  (spy :03 (vec (apply concat (seq ctx))))
  (spy :04 `(let ~(vec (apply concat (seq ctx)))
              ~expr))
  (eval `(let ~(vec (apply concat (seq ctx)))
           ~expr)))

(dotest
  (nl)
  (spy :100
    (contextual-eval '{a 1 b 2}
      '(+ a b)))
  (nl)
  (spy :200
    (contextual-eval '{a 1
                       b (+ a 3)}
      '(+ a b)))
  )
```

with result

```
:01 => {a 1, b 2}
:02 => ([a 1] [b 2])
:03 => [a 1 b 2]
:04 => (clojure.core/let [a 1 b 2] (+ a b))
:100 => 3

:01 => {a 1, b (+ a 3)}
:02 => ([a 1] [b (+ a 3)])
:03 => [a 1 b (+ a 3)]
:04 => (clojure.core/let [a 1 b (+ a 3)] (+ a b))
:200 => 5
```

and in `project.clj` you need to add a dependency to [the Tupelo library](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo)

```
[tupelo "0.9.138"]
```

---

### Update #2:

@amalloy is correct that his example works.  However, it then fails with the original example:

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use demo.core tupelo.core tupelo.test))

(defn contextual-eval [ctx expr]
  (println :01 ctx)
  (println :02 (seq ctx))
  (println :04a (map (fn [[k v]] [k `'~v]) ctx))
  (println :04b  (mapcat (fn [[k v]] [k `'~v]) ctx))
  (println :05 `(let [~@(mapcat (fn [[k v]]
                                  [k `'~v]) ctx)]
                  ~expr))
  (spy :99 (eval
             `(let [~@(mapcat (fn [[k v]]
                                [k `'~v]) ctx)]
                ~expr))))

(dotest
  (newline)
  (throws?
    (println :100
      (contextual-eval '{a 2, b 5}
        '(- (first a) b))))

  (newline)
  (is= -4
    (let [a (range 5)
          b (last a)]
      (spy :300
        (contextual-eval {'a a, 'b b}
          '(- (first a) b)))))  )
```

with result:

```
:01 {a 2, b 5}
:02 ([a 2] [b 5])
:04a ([a (quote 2)] [b (quote 5)])
:04b (a (quote 2) b (quote 5))
:05 (clojure.core/let [a (quote 2) b (quote 5)] (- (first a) b))

:01 {a (0 1 2 3 4), b 4}
:02 ([a (0 1 2 3 4)] [b 4])
:04a ([a (quote (0 1 2 3 4))] [b (quote 4)])
:04b (a (quote (0 1 2 3 4)) b (quote 4))
:05 (clojure.core/let [a (quote (0 1 2 3 4)) b (quote 4)] (- (first a) b))
:99 => -4
:300 => -4
```

The first attempt fails with the exception:

```
  actual: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Don't know how to create ISeq from: java.lang.Long
```

So, I would say that something this fragile may not be the best example for teaching quoting/unquoting in Clojure.  Also, unless you are writing a compiler or similar, code like this is *rarely* required.  And, if you ever do require something this intricate & error prone, I would suggest adding in more checks, spreading out the steps, and showing intermediate results to aid in understanding by the reader and debugging by the maintainer.

Comment: You are right.  I thought when I tried earlier with just **v**, it gave an error.  But now that I tried it again, the code works without the funny looking **`'~v**.

Thank you so much for replying.  Can I ask what the **spy** in your code does, cause it gives me an error when I try to paste your code.

Comment: Thank you again.  I'll take your advice regarding the other books and come back to "Joy of Clojure" ..once I'm sufficiently versed with it.

Comment: This is not a typo. The quoting is important. Try it with more complicated data in your map: For example, `(let [a (range 5), b (last a)] (contextual-eval {'a a, 'b b} '(- (first a) b)))`. The version from the book works, while yours will fail.

Comment: @amalloy : Thank you. I guess I need to really understand the whole macro quoting properly.. it's a bit of a dark magic for me :)

Comment: @Alan Thompson : Thank you for taking the time to try all these examples.  I will revisit this when I have a better understanding of macros :)